# "World" database (cities, towns, villages): create or not create

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I am developing an application with Yii php framework which highly depends on user-specified location.

Of course, I can not allow users to freely submit the name of their city and country.

I am at the crossroads here: should I create the database after all or is there an option to use some reliable API (maybe from Google) to fill my registration form with suggested cities and verify their presence.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: if your application is made for global use. Means your application will use anywhere around the world in future, go for Google API, otherwise database is good practice for this purpose.

Comment: turns out I can't permanently store the google's place_id in my database, so I guess I will turn to creating my own database after all, as cumbersome as it may be. I don't want to be dependent on a third-party anyway, especially if they try to radically restrict the usage of their API.

Comment: yes it's better practice to make database at your end.

Comment: Look at options like maxmind or ip2location.